# secure-file-priv on MySQL for Mac with no .cnf file

Tags: mysql

So I'm unable to locate the cnf file for MySQL on my mac in order to turn off secure-file-priv. Can I possibly create a new .cnf file in order to disable secure-file-priv on my mac?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by default there is no `.cnf` file on a new MySQL Server installation. You have to create it yourself. Otherwise all the options use their built-in default values.

Refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html for the locations where MySQL Server will search for option files. The Mac acts like a UNIX-variant operating system, the `.cnf` file may be in `/etc/my.cnf` for example.